# Runtime Error on CodeChef: SIGSEGV

Tags: segmentation-fault

I am trying to run a code as a solution on codechef for this question:**
https://www.codechef.com/problems/SIMDISH

Though it is compiling and giving the correct output on my cmd, yet it shows Run Time error on Codechef's submission. I googled up for the issue and could not find any problem with my code. There is one constraint in the question I am unable to use: 1 ≤ T ≤ 200, where T is the variable 'pairs' in my code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define INGREDIENT 4

int main()
{
    int pairs;
    int c[INGREDIENT]={0};
    char ingredient1[INGREDIENT][11];
    char ingredient2[INGREDIENT][11];
    scanf("%d", &pairs);
    int i,j,k;
    for (i = 0; i < pairs; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <INGREDIENT; j++)
        {
            scanf("%s", ingredient1[j]);
        }
        for (j = 0; j <INGREDIENT; j++)
        {
            scanf("%s", ingredient2[j]);
        }
        for (k = 0; k <4; k++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                if(strcmp(ingredient1[k], ingredient2[j]) == 0)
                    ++c[i];
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < pairs; i++)
    {
        if (c[i]>=2)
        {
            printf("similar\n");
        }
        else
            printf("dissimilar\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`

I also checked the other solutions, and one of them which is accepted is pretty similar to mine. Can't therefore make out the issue. Check this one, it is accepted, and similar to mine:

```
#include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<math.h>
 //practice question
 int main()
 {
    int i,t,l,j,k,count=0;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    char name1[4][11];
    char name2[4][11];
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        count=0;
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
        scanf("%s",name1[j]);
        }
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
        scanf("%s",name2[j]);
        }

        for(k=0;k<4;k++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<4;j++)
                {
                    l=strcmp(name1[k],name2[j]);
                    if(l==0)
                    {
                        count++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }
        if(count>=2)
        printf("similar\n");
        else
        printf("dissimilar\n");
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/7589/why-do-i-get-a-sigsegv

Comment: Hi. Yes I did check this having realized this is a common error that beginners get. But still could not figure out much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a friend, I found out the issue is that I have declared

```
int c[INGREDIENT]={0}; where INGREDIENT = 4
```

But I am trying to access beyond the limit of 4 elements, everytime the variable 'pairs' is greater than 4

```
for (i = 0; i < pairs; i++)
{
    if (c[i]>=2)
```

Need to use, may be a malloc function for this. Or may be calloc, since I want to initialize the array c to 0::

```
int* c;
c = (int*) calloc(pairs, sizeof(int));
```

Also end with :

```
free(c);
```